# RStudio: Trouble uploading an Excel file. "No package called 'pkgconfig'

Tags: microsoft-excel, packages, r, rstudio

I was able to import an excel spreadsheet into RStudio and work on it while at work, so I decided to email myself the same spreadsheet and work on it at home as well. When I downloaded the excel file and tried to import it into the RStudio environment at home, I get this error message:

"Is this a valid Excel file?
there is no package called 'pkgconfig'"

I've tried a fresh install of R and RStudio, simply installing pkgconfig, and updating as many packages as possible and I still receive this error message.

I also tried converting the Excel file to a .csv where I received a similar error message, "there is no package called 'pkgconfig'".

In trying this code:

> library(readxl)
>
> FinancialSpreadsheet <- read_excel("FinancialSpreadsheet.xlsx")

I receive:

Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
there is no package called ‘pkgconfig’

I feel I am possibly overlooking something obvious because I am fairly new to this language and software. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758129/error-in-loadnamespacename-there-is-no-package-called-rcpp

This actually just answered my question! Apparently R was storing packages in a different place than where it was looking to pull those packages from.

Answer (score 0):

- Part of the problem was pkgconfig was not installed
- also, with windows, the current directory often changes and should never be relied on. You can use an if statement combined with something like file.exists(fileNamePath) to perform a test.
- read_excel requires parameters to be set up path should point to a file-name-path

### example

```
....
  #install up required packages
install.packages("pkgconfig")
install.packages("Rcpp")
install.packages("readxl")

  #load up required packages
library(pkgconfig)
library(Rcpp)
library(readxl)

  #load up an excel spreadsheet into a variable object called datasets
filePath <- "C:/.../extdata/evaluation/"

fileName <- 'GPW Detailed Tables March 2019 - STP.xlsx'
fileNamePath <- paste0(filePath, fileName)

  #TEST FILE is where you think it is
file.exists(fileNamePath)

#read_excel(datasets)
#FinancialSpreadsheet <- read_excel("FinancialSpreadsheet.xlsx")

#return data into a tibble Data Frame
datasets <- read_xlsx(path = fileNamePath, 
                      sheet = '1a', 
                      range = "D18:L26")

#return data result to the terminal screen
read_excel(path = fileNamePath, 
           sheet = '1a', 
           range = "D18:L26")
....
```

#### example O/P using a spreadsheet on my box

```
....

> fileNamePath <- paste0(filePath, fileName)
> file.exists(fileNamePath)
[1] TRUE
> datasets <- read_xlsx(path = fileNamePath, 
+                       sheet = '1a', 
+                       range = "D18:L26")
New names:
* `` -> ...2
* `` -> ...3
> 

> read_excel(path = fileNamePath, 
+            sheet = '1a', 
+            range = "D18:L26")
New names:
* `` -> ...2
* `` -> ...3
# A tibble: 8 x 9
  `Lancashire and South C~ ...2  ...3               `1263` `689` `255` `8`   `185` `145`
  <chr>                    <lgl> <chr>               <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 00Q                      NA    NHS Blackburn wit~    110    65    19 -        11    16
2 00R                      NA    NHS Blackpool CCG      97    56    16 1        17     8
3 00X                      NA    NHS Chorley and S~    125    59    33 1        18    14
4 01A                      NA    NHS East Lancashi~    313   153    61 2        41    63
5 01E                      NA    NHS Greater Prest~    148    68    35 2        32    13
6 01K                      NA    NHS Morecambe Bay~    279   176    60 2        34     8
7 02G                      NA    NHS West Lancashi~     72    42    10 -         8    13
8 02M                      NA    NHS Fylde and Wyr~    130    71    23 -        24    13
> 

....
```